# Mouse Drag To Zoom implementation Java - not on click

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have written some code to implement a drag to zoom (i.e. draw a rectangle with the mouse and then zoom into this area so it fills the container) on a JPanel. However, before I wrote this into the Listener, I had a "mouseClicked" method, which is still there. This method performed a different function, simply returning the coords of the click.

Unfortunately, I mistakenly implemented the zoom function using MousePressed, which thus runs at the same time as the mouseClicked event. This means that when I click the mouse to get the coordinates, it also zooms in on a very small rectangle. Is there anyway to change this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, and please let me know if you need anything clarifying!

Here is the listener class:

class panelClickListener extends MouseAdapter implements            MouseMotionListener  {

```
    JLabel toShowCoords, rangeLabel;
    juliaPanel panelJulia;
    mandPanel panelMand;
    int startX, startY, currentX, currentY;
    boolean dragging;
    ComplexNumber startRange, endRange;

    public panelClickListener(JLabel toShowCoordsIn, juliaPanel panelJuliaIn, mandPanel panelMandIn, JLabel rangeLabelIn) {
        toShowCoords = toShowCoordsIn;
        panelJulia = panelJuliaIn;
        panelMand = panelMandIn;
        rangeLabel = rangeLabelIn;
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)   {   
        int x = e.getX();   
        int y = e.getY();   
        userSelectedPoint = pointsToDrawOn[x][y];
        toShowCoords.setText("Number Selected: " + userSelectedPoint.getReal() + " , " + userSelectedPoint.getImaginary());
        panelJulia.setFixedNumber(pointsToDrawOn[x][y]);
        panelJulia.repaint();
    } 

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        Point point = event.getPoint();
        startX = point.x;
        startY = point.y;
        dragging = true;
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        dragging = false;
        startRange = pointsToDrawOn[startX][startY];
        endRange = pointsToDrawOn[currentX][currentY];
        maxVal = endRange;
        minVal = startRange;
        rangeLabel.setText("Real axis: " + minVal.getReal() + "," + maxVal.getReal() + " - Imaginary axis: " + minVal.getImaginary() + "," + maxVal.getImaginary());
        populatePointArray();
        panelMand.repaint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        Point p = event.getPoint();
        currentX = p.x;
        currentY = p.y;
    }

}
```

Comment: dragging should only be set to true when mouseDragged is called, then when mouseReleased is called, you need to check to see if dragging is true before processing the zoom

Comment: There's some theory to go with that comment, mouseClicked will only be called if the point of the mouse is the same for mousePressed and mouseReleased. So in a click operation you can expect mousePressed, mouseReleased and mouseClicked to be called (I believe in that order, but you'd better test it). In a drag operation, you can expect mousePressed, mouseDragged and mouseReleased to be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dragging` should only be set to `true` when `mouseDragged` is called, then when `mouseReleased` is called, you need to check to see if dragging is `true` before processing the zoom

There's some theory to go with that, `mouseClicked` will only be called if the point of the mouse is the same for `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased`.

So in a click operation you can expect `mousePressed`, `mouseReleased` and `mouseClicked` to be called (I believe in that order, but you'd better test it).

In a drag operation, you can expect `mousePressed`, `mouseDragged` and `mouseReleased` to be called

Comment: Hi MadProgrammer - many thanks for the reply, and for the theory alongside it. The order you suggest is correct after my testing, so you were right! Furthermore I have implemented the solution by moving the `dragging` boolean variable, and this worked brilliant. Answer marked as correct, thanks for your help!